# Get a reference to react-native created image views from Objective-C

Tags: ios, imageview, react-native, uiview-hierarchy

How do I get a reference to one of the react-native created image views from Objective-C.

I have a basic react native app that I created with the following js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var FaceSdkNativeBridge = NativeModules.ViewController;
FaceSdkNativeBridge.init('msg');

// class ReactFaceSdk extends Component {
var ReactFaceSdk = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native! Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Image
          style={[styles.cameraFeedImage, this.border('green')]}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  },
  border: function(color) {
    return {
      borderColor: color,
      borderWidth: 4
    }
  }
});
// }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  cameraFeedImage: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactFaceSdk', () => ReactFaceSdk);
```

I want to access that  component (RCTImageView) from Objective-c side. How would I get a reference to that?

This is what my AppDelegate.m looks like

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"ReactFaceSdk"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];    
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

p.s : reference of how view hierarchy looks like
[image]